# OnCollisionEnter not working

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, unityscript, gameobject

I have a problem with my onCollisionEnter function in Unity3d. The thing is i have a 3rd person controller who if collides with a boudary object should activate another gameobject and a label.

this is how i have given my code

```
function OnCollisionEnter(collision : Collision)
{
   if(collision.gameobject1.tag=="tag1")
   {
     // activate game object and label
   }
   if(collision.gameobject2.tag=="tag2")
   {
      // deactivate game object and label
   }
}
```

the problem is it is entering both the loops and i dunno whether what i have given is wrong or the way i have given. Where am i going wrong?

Comment: Are the colliders attached to the gameobject or a child gameobject?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the OnCollisionEnter event is firing (you could add a print to make sure), then there are two things to check: tags and colliders

**Tags**

Try

```
collision.transform.tag
```

Also verify that you have selected the right tag for the gameobject.

**Colliders**

In Unity3D the collision callbacks (onCollisionEnter, etc) only happen under certain circumstances.  EX: A gameobject (gameobject1) with a collider and rigidbody component will collide with a static (not moving) gameobject (gameobject2) that just has a collider.

I would look at [Box Collider Reference](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Components/class-BoxCollider.html) because at the bottom is a **Collision action matrix** that explains under what conditions collisions occur.

Answer (score 0):

Please add tags to Unity. Perhaps you don't add tags to objects. Please add `tag1` and `tag2` to your tags, select your objects, and select `tag1` or `tag2`.

[image]